# .desktop files in non standard directories

Tags: environment-variables, desktop-environment, freedesktop

I'm providing some applications to the users of my system through the use of an environment modules manager (i.e. [Lmod](http://lmod.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)). So I have a bunch of self-compiled applications out of the standard tree: for example let's assume I have software installed in `/software`. Among those applications there are some of them that provide `.desktop`entries. As example let's assume I recompiled a more recent version of evince: `/software/evince/2.32`, such that I have respectively `/software/evince/2.32/bin` `/software/evince/2.32/lib` `/software/evince/2.32/share/applications/evince.desktop`.

In the `modulefiles` what you do is to prepend to `PATH, LD_LIBRARY_PATH` ecc... the path to the self compiled applications in a way that, when you do `module load evince`, then in the `$PATH`you're gonna have a more recent version available.

I would like to be able to do the same with `desktop` entries in order to be able to give to users additional (or more up to date) Desktop applications. Is there an env variable I can update to let the WM be able to get the `desktop`files from additional directories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to do this:

The first option is to update `$XDG_DATA_DIRS` variable. However, your `.desktop` files must be in `$XDG_DATA_DIRS/applications/` directory. So, you need to create `/software/applications` directory for the `.desktop` files and append `/software` to `$XDG_DATA_DIRS`. After that, run the `update-desktop-database` command to update the caches. This is provided by the `desktop-utils` package.

The other option is to run `xdg-desktop-menu install` on the `.desktop` files. This program is part of `xdg-utils` and will automatically take care of any non-standard environments and can be run by normal user as well. It also makes uninstallation easier since you can just run `xdg-desktop-menu uninstall`. See `man xdg-desktop-menu` for details.

My personal recommendation would be to use the various `xdg-utils` programs for any desktop related updates. They are much easier to deal with than messing around with environment variables.

Comment: Does `$XDG_DATA_DIRS` work as for `$PATH`: column-separated list of directories?

Comment: Yes, same as that.